# Как слушать события с вебсокета в Java?

Tags: java, websocket

Здравствуйте. Не могу осилить такую вот задачу. Есть java-проект, но не web, а standalone. Простое консольное приложение. В нем нужно реализовать клиента, который будет подключаться по известному адресу к вебсокету и постоянно слушать события с него. Гугл в качестве примеров приводит реализации клиентов разными библиотеками, но везде все сводится к тому, что клиент подключается к сокету, отправляет сообщение, получает ответ и закрывается. При этом выставляется таймаут ожидания ответа от сокета. Мне же нужно, чтобы это ожидание было "бесконечным", то есть прослушивание должно идти непрерывно. Подскажите, как это можно реализовать и средствами какой библиотеки? Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

вот посмотри https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket
можно использовать как для web так и приложениях

Answer (score 1):

На клиенте создаешь сокет(`java.net.Socket`)

```
Socket socket = new Socket(ip, port);
```

С помощью метода `getOutputStream()` получаешь поток для отправки сообщений на сервер.
С помощью метода `getInputStream()` получаешь поток для получения сообщений от сервера.

Заканчиваешь использование методом `close()`.

Например:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(ip, port);
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    oos.writeObject(new String("some string #" + i));
}
socket.close();
```

На сервере(`java.net.ServerSocket`):

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
```

Ловишь соединение с помощью метода `accept()`.

```
Socket socket = server.accept();
```

Например:

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
while (true) {
    Socket socket = server.accept();
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    while (!socket.isClosed()) {
        System.out.println((String) ois.readObject());
    }
}
server.close();
```

Comment: не про такие сокеты речь идет)

Answer (score 0):

> вот посмотри https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket можно использовать как для web так и приложениях

У этой библиотеки наблюдаются проблемы с wss о чем пишет сам автор. Есть ли реализация с поддержкой wss?

В JavaScript с нужным мне сокетом работает без проблем:

```js
var socket = new WebSocket("wss://my.example.host/");
    
    socket.onopen = function() {
    alert("Соединение установлено.");        socket.send('newitems');
    };

    socket.onclose = function(event) {
    if (event.wasClean) {
    alert('Соединение закрыто чисто');
    } else {
    alert('Обрыв соединения'); // например, "убит" процесс сервера
    }
    alert('Код: ' + event.code + ' причина: ' + event.reason);
    };

    socket.onmessage = function(event) {
    alert("Получены данные " + event.data);
    };

    socket.onerror = function(error) {
    alert("Ошибка " + error.message);
    };
```

Comment: Верхние два абзаца вашего ответа — это на самом деле комментарий к ответу выше. Когда будет 15 репутации, вы сможете комментировать и запостить их именно как комментарий.

Comment: А вот остальное — про Javascript, и совсем не решает вопрос автора, который про Java.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin, видимо это вопрос.

Comment: @Visman: вроде работает без проблем. Непонятно )

Comment: у меня несколько проектив работающих на wss - работает без проблем. Причём клиенты и браузер и андроид - всё соединено с одним сервером. Есть наработки - могу поделиться опытом, обращайтесь (основа  -та библиотека)

Comment: @Вадим Как с этим бороться?

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.websocket.DeploymentException: SSL handshake has failed`

Comment: @Anatoliy Samokisha надо посмотреть весь код, так трудно ...

Comment: @Вадим пример брал [отсюда](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26452903/javax-websocket-client-simple-example) WebSocket `wss://market.dota2.net/wsn/`. Канал не важен т.к. ошибка еще на этапе подключения.

Во втором примере вывод таков `closed connection
Exception in thread "main" org.java_websocket.exceptions.WebsocketNotConnectedException` т.е. соединение не открывается, и после отправки сообщения ошибка.

Comment: @Anatoliy Samokisha можешь скинуть проект, что б конкретную реализацию посмотреть.

Comment: @Вадим проекта уже как бы нет, но вот реализация websocket меня мучает. Все что есть это пример по ссылке выше. Хочу чтобы непрерывно выводил входящие сообщения в консоль, а дальше обработать не проблема. В данный момент проблемы наблюдаются на стадии подключения. Все что есть [здесь](http://pastebin.com/Z5HrP040).

Comment: @Anatoliy Samokisha а где про сертификат? wss подразумевает использование сертификата. Вот пример для клиента по wss https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/blob/master/src/main/example/SSLClientExample.java сервер тоже должен быть с сертификатом